# Azure showing wrong status for virtual machines

Tags: azure

I have a script that once a minute gets the running status of one of our virtual machines in Azure. The reason for the script is that I suspect the machine to report wrong status occasionally. The script shows that this machine report empty status, or 'VM starting', for a couple of minutes a couple of times a day. The machine has not been restarted and Azure Monitoring shows the machine has been up. I can see in our Prometheus / Grafana stack that this happens to most of our machines. MS support has checked and can not see any problems. I have provided them with a screen shot showing the machine is showing 'Starting'.

This is the script:

```
Set-AzContext -Subscription '<Subscription>'
while ($true) {
    try {
        $Date = $(get-date).ToString()
        $VM = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName '<Resource group>' -Name '<VM name>' -Status
        if ($VM.Statuses[1].DisplayStatus -ne 'VM running') {
            Write-Output ($Date + "  " + $VM.Statuses[1].DisplayStatus)
        }
    }
    catch {
        Write-Output ($(get-date).ToString() + "  " + $VM.Name)
        $errorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
        $line = $_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber
        Write-Output "Unexpected exception: $errorMessage at $line"
    }
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
}
```

Output from last 24 hours:

```
2024-02-20 09:56:29
2024-02-20 10:07:04
2024-02-20 21:21:01
2024-02-21 03:29:14
2024-02-21 03:30:44
2024-02-21 03:32:15
2024-02-21 03:33:52
2024-02-21 03:35:30
2024-02-21 03:37:00  VM starting
2024-02-21 03:38:01  VM starting
2024-02-21 03:39:02  VM starting
2024-02-21 03:40:07  VM starting
2024-02-21 03:41:08  VM starting
2024-02-21 03:42:08  VM starting
```

This VM was last rebooted 2024-01-24.

This script runs 24/7 on my laptop, I have a similar script written in Python running in a Kubernetes cluster in Azure, gathering data for Prometheus, showing the same error.

Is anyone else experiencing this?

I have logged the problem to MS, but they claim nothing is wrong. I am expecting the Azure portal and API to show correct status at all times.

Comment: Sometimes, Powershell commands may give incorrect results, you can also check the same result using **Azure CLI** cmdlet: az vm show -g 'rg-name" -n 'VM-Name' -d --query 'powerState'

Comment: Yes, I know, the script in Kubernetes is written in Python, and I have seen the same error in the portal, this makes me suspect the problem is within Azure. But good point, I will make a script that uses Azure CLI as well.

Comment: I have added an Azure CLI command to fetch the status:

    $VMCLI = az vm show -g '<Resource group>' -n '<VM name>' -d --query 'powerState'

This is the output:

```
PS: 2024-02-22 09:35:49
CLI: 2024-02-22 09:35:49  ""
PS: 2024-02-22 09:37:53
CLI: 2024-02-22 09:37:53  ""
PS: 2024-02-22 09:51:03  VM starting
CLI: 2024-02-22 09:51:03  "VM starting"
PS: 2024-02-22 11:23:11
CLI: 2024-02-22 11:23:11  ""
```
That is, Powershell and Azure CLI gives the same result, to me that indicates Azure is giving the wrong status through the API.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, PowerShell commands may give incorrect results, you can also check the same result using **Azure CLI**.

```
    while ($true) {
        try {
            $Date = $(get-date).ToString()
            $VM = az vm show -g 'rithwik' -n 'testVM-0' -d --query 'powerState'
                Write-Output ($Date + "  " + $VM)
        }
        catch {
            Write-Output ($(get-date).ToString() + "  " + $VM.Name)
            $errorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
            $line = $_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber
            Write-Output "Unexpected exception: $errorMessage at $line"
        }
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]

If you still encounter any issue, please update the module to the latest version using the following steps:

```
Update-Module -Name Az -Force
```

Comment: Thanks! I have updated the modules but the same problem, both for Powershell and Azure CLI. As I said, I have seen wrong status in the portal as well, which makes me think there is something not quite right in the backend.